# How should I draw on ViewController's default View?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xcode4.2

XCode 4.2 (the only version of XCode I've ever used) creates a ViewController with a default View property.

I cannot see the code for this default View so I cannot draw on it (because I cannot access drawRect). Is that correct?

Assuming answer to the above is that I cannot draw. If I want to draw on the window should I:

1. Add a subview to the default View and then draw (via drawRect) on the subview? or
2. Replace the default View with one that I create and can therefore draw on via drawRect?

This is not a question of how to do this, I want to know what would be the best way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do custom drawing in you view, then you should define your own custom `UIView` class, where you override `drawRect` to do the custom drawing.

Now, wether you follow either approach 1. or 2. depends on what your app does. Both are perfectly reasonable.

Say, for example, that you would like to do your custom drawing, but also show some kind of controls (e.g. to clear the drawing, to reset it, and so on), then I think it could be a better design if you have a root view that you add both the custom view and the other view to as subviews. But this is just an example and it depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Hope this helps a bit...